# How does $('<html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>') work?

Tags: jquery, document

I am still trying to create a full DOM `document` from a string. I got a bunch of interesting suggestions on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598791/create-a-dom-document-from-string-without-jquery), but none actually fits what I'm looking for. So I'm trying to understand how things work to maybe find a solution.

We need to replace a lot of JQuery code with 'native' Javascript. With Jquery, we are able to do `$('<html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>')` and then perform operations on the nodes of this object, search them... etc.

What does Jquery do? Does it create a new document? Append to the existing one?

Since a lot of people question our replacement of Jquery, here is a little more details: we are building a chrome application which will make use of content script. Even if Jquery is lightweight, it's not very kind of us to add a couple MB of memory consumed in each tab for a very few Jquery methods. Jquery *is* awesome and fits many many needs, not ours.

Comment: DocumentFragment didn't work?

Comment: Well, I couldn't find a way to populate the document fragment from a string :(

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't have `innerHTML`.

Comment: `We need to replace a lot of JQuery code with 'native' Javascript.` Why's that?

Comment: My question, too.  Julien, you appear to be asking something like: "We need to replace high-speed trains with bicycles. How can I make this bike go 200 miles per hour?"

Comment: jQuery is a rather chunky library, and if you aren't trying to support old browsers, many of the things it gives you have native functions.

Comment: Ok people, I have added details in why it is not a good idea for us to use Jquery. Feel free to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your answer in the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src). You start out with `core.js`, where you'll find the `init` method. If you follow the logic there, you'll see that for any nontrivial elements it'll call [`jQuery.buildFragment`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L477), which indeed builds a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/DocumentFragment) which it'll populate with the content you specified. That will teach you how to deal with building a DOM tree from a string, including [stripping out various bits of content that you most likely won't want](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L648).

Comment: PS: note http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-or-dom/4 - if you're so concerned for performance, building a structured DOM instead of using strings with `innerHTML` may be faster.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I found out. So, I guess, Jquery first creates the Fragment, then parses the string with innerHTML in the "main" document, and finally copies that over to the fragment?

Comment: The string is parsed by using a `<div>` wrapper and setting its `innerHTML`. Then jQuery collects a list of the div's childNodes, which is appended to the document fragment element by element, each time checking there's no script tags involved. The 'main' document is used to create the div, unless you specify a context with a different document to the initial `$('<html>...')` call as a second argument.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is open-source, so [see for yourself](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.init).

Looks like it uses a combination of `createElement` and `createDocumentFragment`, depending on a few things.

So you cannot use jQuery but you can re-invent it? Seems strange. Try to lose this bizarre requirement.

Comment: I am indeed deep in Jquery's code, but you will have to agree that this is not the easiest thing when you've never dived into it. I assumed somebody would be able to express what Jquery does in Layman's terms :( Maybe I was wrong. Also, I don't want to re-invent Jquery, I just can't use it.

Comment: I can never understand people moving away from jQuery (to another library yes) but its cross browser / used by the masses / small / available on CDN and most of all simple to use and understand ... oh well maybe its just me !

Comment: And to get in more details, we are building a chrome application which will make use of content script. Even if Jquery is lightweight, it's not very kind of us to add a couple MB of memory consumed in each tab for a very few Jquery methods.

Comment: @ManseUK : Cross browser doesn't matter since it's a chrome app. CDN doesn't matter because it will be loaded 'locally'... and small is still big when you have 100 tabs open.

Comment: @JulienGenestoux: The documentation describes what it does "in layman's terms". That's what it is.