# Use jQuery with my own document object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm making a greasemonkey userscript that is supposed to preload certain data (actually, [xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/) strips) and display them when link is clicked.

My task mostly consists of retrieving data from DOM fetched by ajax and assigning the values to DOM the user is viewing. This is one particular case I find jQuery incredibly helpful. *But* jQuery operates on `window.document`.

I load and parse document [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12006048/607407):

```
   xhr.onload = function() {
       var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(
         'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
         'html',
         document.doctype
       );
       doc.documentElement.innerHTML = this.responseText;
   }
```

And I need to perform jQuery selectors on **`doc`**, so that I can retrieve the site data (such as comic title).

Once more, the question: How to perform jQuery selectors on custom document object?

Comment: Does `$(doc)` not work?

Comment: use $(doc).find(selector)

Comment: $(doc) will do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `$(doc)` and jQuery's traversal methods:

```
var $doc = $(doc);

var comicContainer = $doc.find('#comics'); // for example
```

Answer (score 0):

To add, for example, click events to custom loaded items, use this:

```
$(body).on( 'click', 'YOUR_DYNAMIC_SELECTOR', function(){ DO_ALL_THIS } )
```

Comment: What is the `body` variable here?

Comment: It is just the html body. It doesn't have to be the body, ultimately put in there the selector of an element that contains all of your dynamically loaded html.

Comment: The click will fire on click of the item selected in the $(), but will look for YOUR_DYNAMIC_SELECTOR which is relevant to the click