# get input value from html in ajax response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, response

To get the html response of the page, I use:

```
var theUrl = "https://example.com/users/22";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
xmlHttp.send();
var html = xmlHttp.responseText;
```

This will now return a 535 line html page.
If we simply had that source code on our current page, to get the value of the tag (12345) as shown below:

```
<input name="token" type="hidden" value="12345" />
```

we would simply use:

```
document.getElementsByName("token")[0].value;
```

But since the HTML is in the ajax response as a variable named `html` how do I get the value of the input with name token? Can I somehow convert it to a DOM element and then run that code?
javascript only please, no jQuery.
Thanks.

Comment: This answer might help you with your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598791/create-a-dom-document-from-string-without-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Try creating an HTML element, adding the response, and then parse it. 
We need to add a class name to select specific inputs with [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName), or, if you want to select all inputs, you could use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

```
var responseText = '<input name="token" class="token" type="hidden" value="12345" />'
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = responseText;
console.log(el.getElementsByClassName("token")[0].value);
```

Comment: Getting: Uncaught TypeError: el.getElementsByName is not a function.

Comment: Looks like you can only call getElmentsByName on the document. We can call getElemetnsByClassName though on the response

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your xmltHttp.response text like this:

```js
 var xmlString = "<input name='token1' type='hidden' value='12345' />"; // Use your xmlHttp.responseText here. This is for demonstration purposes
 var parser = new DOMParser();
 var element = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/html");
 console.log(element.querySelectorAll('[name="token1"]')[0].value);
```